# Socket Reception interruption when setting socket receiving timeout using select in c linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, timeout, recv

I have a client thread connecting to a socket server in c/linux and blocking to receive data. I want to stop waiting if a timeout expires without receiving something.
I used select to specify a timeout, for instance a timeout of 4 secs, but the thread receives data, and after exactly 4 secs, it stops receiving. Whereas i want to stop waiting after timeout if there is no data received !
This is my client code :

```
int lg=0;
char bufRec[83];
do
{ // init fd_set
  fd_set readfds;
  struct timeval timeout;
  FD_ZERO(&readfds); 
  FD_SET(sFd, &readfds);
  timeout.tv_sec  = 4;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;
  int ret = select(socketFd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  if (ret <= 0)
     break;
  else
    if (FD_ISSET(socketFd, &readfds))
       lg = recv(socketFd, bufRec, sizeof(bufRec), 0);
  } while ( lg > 0);
    
  close(socketFd);
```

I even used setsockopt to specify a timeout, and i have the same result :
`setsockopt (socketFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (struct timeval*)&timeout, sizeof(struct timeval)`

The server socket is created using the following code :
 `int sFd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`

Can anyone help me please ??

I want to code this solution to solve a problem when client disconnects abnormally letting the thread blocked on receiving for several minutes.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre], i.e. show a minimal program we can compile and run and everything we need to reproduce the problem. In this case we probably need a program (or command line, using e.g. netcat) for the other side.

Comment: You have not gathered enough info for us to debug your issue. As a corollary, you yourself cannot debug it either. What is your client doing? Is `recv()` being called? How many times is `select()` being called?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I didn't give the complete example because it is a part of a complex soft. Today, i took server and client parts in isolated programs and try to reproduce my problem to post it, but my example behaves well and the client stops waiting reception when the timeout expires. So the code below works, and i'll try to figure out why it is not working in my soft, or reproduce the problem independently from the soft. Many thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you want to reset the timeout to 4 seconds after any data being received? Or do you want to keep track of a total of 4 seconds? In the latter case, keep subtracting the expired time from the 4 seconds before calling `select`.

Comment: Tanhks Cheatah for your comment. I want to stop waiting receiving data in case 4 seconds expires without receiving something. That's why after a receipt of data, i reset the timeout to 4 seconds.